# JavaScript/JQuery, mobile click not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette, jquery-masonry

Without exposing much details of the project, I have the a `Marionette.Layout` such as

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    'events': {
        'click': "onClick"
    },

    'onClick': function () {
        console.log("Clicked.");
    }
});
```

Many of these layouts are created and are loaded asynchronously into a container div as the page scrolls to populate a feed.  The issue arises when scrolling and clicking.  Sometimes the clicks won't register for a short while after scrolling and on rare occasions they don't fire when not scrolling; requiring two~three taps before the click registers.

At first I thought it was an issue related to `Marionette` itself, but when I added the following in the `console`, it also did not fire:

```
$('body').on('click', '.myviewclass', function () {
    console.log("Body registered click.");
});
```

This issue isn't consistent, but happens every once in awhile.
**Example code**: http://jsfiddle.net/k8vWj/

**Note**: Fiddle is just an example of what the code looks like, whether or not the problem is reproducible there I'm not sure, as the site isn't very mobile friendly.

Comment: are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: Sorry, have updated question.  I am not using JQuery mobile.

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.myviewclass', function () {...} add dot before class

Comment: I have that, was a typo, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Use events on Layout. Layout is just for setting the HTML structure of the App and you can add Regions to it accordingly.
Check this : https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md

You can add events to Views. (ItemView/CollectionView/CompositeView)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$('body').on('touchstart click', '.myviewclass', function () {
    console.log("Body registered click.");
});
```